# Fcitx doesn't work with Viber in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, fcitx

My computer runs Arch Linux and I use fcitx to write my native language. I have installed `fictx`, `fcitx-unikey`, `fcitx-im`, `fcitx-configtool`, and it works well with any software I have here except Viber.

It seems that Fcitx doesn't recognize Viber typing environment.

So what should I do?

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit later, but anyway ;-)

Viber uses its own copy of LibQt5 located in /opt/viber/lib and /opt/viber/plugins/. In order to make Fcitx[5] working with this copy of Qt, you need to put the relevant Fcitx input plugin for Qt. In case of Fcitx5 it's merely a symlink from `/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitx5platforminputcontextplugin.so` to `/opt/viber/plugins/platforminputcontexts/` like this:

```
ln -sf ../../../../usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitx5platforminputcontextplugin.so \
    /opt/viber/plugins/platforminputcontexts/
```

I have discovered this recipe in https://github.com/vinhjaxt/fcitx5-unikey

Comment: Does not work for me, kubuntu 22.04.01, fcitx5 5.0.14-1